# Matching dates, both strings, don't 'match'?

Tags: python-3.x, string, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to use an IF statement to trigger smtp to fire emails and, for whatever reason, my matching strings aren't being interpreted as a match.

Here's what I'm working with:
I'm importing everything I need and setting 'yesterday' as a string.

```
import csv, sqlite3
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday = str(yesterday)
```

I built a scraper to grab jobs from various sites and drop them to a csv file. Then, I'm iterating over my csv file and grabbing all rows that match my 'skills' criteria:

```
skills = ('ninja')
csv_data = csv.DictReader(open('jobs.csv'))

for row in csv_data:
    if skills in row.get('address', '').lower():
        print("match")
        print(row['day'])
        print(type(row['day']))
        print(yesterday)
        print(type(yesterday))
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs_table(day, 
                                            link,  
                                            description,  
                                            compensation,  
                                            employment_type, 
                                            images,  
                                            address) 
                                           VALUES(:day, 
                                                  :link,  
                                                  :description,   
                                                  :compensation,   
                                                  :employment_type,   
                                                  :images,   
                                                  :address)", row,) 
db.commit()
```

All of that works fine, and uploads jobs to my database. The output for 'print' gives me:

```
match
2019-06-14
<class 'str'>
2019-06-25
<class 'str'>
match
2019-06-25
<class 'str'>
2019-06-25
<class 'str'>
match
2019-06-25
<class 'str'>
2019-06-25
<class 'str'>
```

After that, it runs:

```
cur.execute(f"SELECT description, link 
              FROM jobs_table WHERE day = {yesterday}")

results = cur.fetchall()
if results:
    for result in results:
        result = str(result)
        result = result.replace("'",'')
        result = result.replace('(','')
        result = result.replace(')','')
        send_email(result)
else:
    print('No Results In The Database')
print('')        
print('')

db.close()
```

And it prints out:

```
No Results In The Database
```

Which I don't understand because, as mentioned above, both my database's 'day' and datetime's 'yesterday' are matching strings.

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: `yesterday` looks like `2019-06-14`, right? Another victim of trying to put values directly in a statement instead of binding them to parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a f-string to insert the date, I'd do it this way:

```
cur.execute(
    "SELECT description, link FROM jobs_table WHERE day = :day",
    {
        "day": yesterday
    }
)
```

The parameterization will make sure it gets quoted properly in the SQL, and also saves you from a bunch of other potential escaping and data-quality mishaps.

Some examples of using parameters in execute commands can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects

Comment: This did it! Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have made my own test-application, where I connect to a database.
the following code prints true, and is writing to match yours.

```
cur.execute("SELECT description, link FROM jobs_table WHERE day=" + yesterday)
results = cur.fetchall()
if results:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Use 'strftime' on your (yesterday) value, and change (day) in your database to varchar.

```
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

'20190625'

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
cur.execute("SELECT description, link 
                      FROM jobs_table WHERE DATE(day) = DATE({yesterday})")
```

instead of

```
cur.execute(f"SELECT description, link 
                      FROM jobs_table WHERE day = {yesterday}")
```

time may differ in Date type column.

Comment: Worth a shot, but it didn't change the output.\